# Boot Successful after Emptying Root Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel, root

I was trying to install a new kernel (for fun). I downloaded linux-5.2.9 kernel(in my root partition in /usr/src) and then built it with `make` and `make modules install`.

But while booting from the `grub` I wasn't able to boot it initially with the booting process hangs at `[OK] Listening on ....` or similar. Then I went into recovery mode and deleted source files of linux-5.2.9 to make some space in root partition and bang, all kernels boot successfully(with some errors and failures).

So my question is, why making space in the root partition allowed it to boot and why does space in root partition matter while booting?

Answer (score 2):

Trying new kernels is always a good idea... however installing them without the package system is not so good: The [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) Wiki describes how you should do it in the future.

Running `make` and `make module_install` in the kernel source is only the second step. How did you configure the kernel? Usually you would follow these steps:

1. Configure the kernel: A good choice is to use the configuration of the running kernel form `/boot/config-<kernel version>`

   ```
   $ cp /boot/config-5.0.0-25-generic /usr/src/ linux-5.2.9/.config
   $ cd /usr/src/linux-5.2.9/ && make menuconfig
   ```

   **Update** Configuring the kernel with `make defconfig` will create a working kernel, however it has only a minimal set of drivers configured. E.g. it might not work with current graphic cards or SATA chips.
2. Build and install modules (as you did)

   ```
   $ make && make module_install
   ```
3. Copy the kernel into `/boot`. The available images depend on your kernel configuration

   ```
   $ cp arch/x86/boot/bzimage /boot/vmlinuz
   ```
4. Create `initrd`. That is the part you properly missed, the default kernel will not boot without a `initrd` image. You can do that manually too, but there is a useful script for that [update-initramfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/live-update-initramfs.8.html):

   ```
   $ update-initramfs -c -k 5.2.9
   ```
5. Add new entry to `grup`. The [update-grub](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-grub.8.html) can do that, however it requires, that you kernel and modules have the same naming convention.

   ```
   $ update-grub
   ```

And to answer your question: The space in the `/` or `/boot` partition has no effect on the Linux kernel. In fact the kernel does not need both partitions at all. The Ubuntu recovery mode e.g. only needs the `initrd` and start the `busybox` shell.

So deleting the kernel source under `/usr/src` did not fix your problem. It must be something else you did.

Comment: Hmmm... I configured it with `make defconfig`. Grub was updated with new kernel but it would not boot and pause indefinitely, so I went into recovery mode of the kernel and through the root terminal did `cd /usr/src` and deleted kernel source `rm -r linux-5.2.9`. Then rebooted and it worked. Interesting to know that this was not the cause for it to work and that space in '/' or '/boot` has no effect on Linux kernel. Weird!

Comment: Did execute `update-grub`, `apt-get upgrade` or `apt upgrade`... all of them could fix the problem.